# Variable populated in Controller's constructor is missing in further wizard

Tags: visualforce

We are using wizard i.e. one controller (extension) and many visualforce pages. We are initializing required variable on controller's constructor using standard controller.getRecord() method. But sometime the already set variable value is missing in further pages and getting "caused by: System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject" because the id which we are setting up in constructor is being used in SOQL query further.

Error is coming only on Service Cloud Console.

Comment: Can you confirm that the variable is not marked as transient? The constructor isn't run when view state is used to recreate the controller for later pages but any non-transient field should be restored.

Comment: Post relevant code plz.